# Getting part from current url with jQuery

Tags: jquery, url

I'm using $(location).attr("href") to get the current url something that works fine. But as I'm using it to activate or not menu options, some complicated URLs does not help me. That's why I want to find a solution to get part of the url till the first appearance of &.

As an example from a url like:
https://www.cmsforo.com/admincp.php?do=sections&action=add
I want to get just the part:
https://www.cmsforo.com/admincp.php?do=sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `.split()` on `&`.

```
let url = $(location).attr("href");
let requiredUrl = url.split('&')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like `url.split('&')[0]`? Should work for your particular example